# Error in query using string in path flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```py
def get(self, reference):
   image = ImageModel.find(reference)
```

In find method is returned a object image using a 'name' as attribute.

If I use `cls.query.filter(cls._reference.like("img.jpg")).first()` is returned an image object, but using `cls.query.filter(cls._reference.like(f"{reference}")).first()` or `cls.query.filter(cls._reference.like(reference)).first()`return `None`

My route is `"/image/<path:reference>"`, with `GET` method.

Comment: Can you provide source for the `/image/<path:reference>` view handler? Can you provide an example of a URL that would call this view handler?

Comment: I receive the value as string using this url: `localhost/image/'img.jpg'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `'img.jpg'` as `path` in `/image/<path:reference>`, your `reference` will literally be `'img.jpg'` (note the single quotes). That would result in `cls.query.filter(cls._reference.like("'img.jpg'")).first()` when you try to query/filter against `reference`.

Comment: I solved changing the route to `/image` and using a parameter to pass a reference. The route would receiver a reference like `folder/img.jpg`, that results in error. Thank you for help :)